# Memory Information of each process in c++

Tags: c++, winapi

```
typedef struct _PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX {
  DWORD  cb;
  DWORD  PageFaultCount;
  SIZE_T PeakWorkingSetSize;
  SIZE_T WorkingSetSize;
  SIZE_T QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T PagefileUsage;
  SIZE_T PeakPagefileUsage;
  SIZE_T PrivateUsage;
} 
PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX, *PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX;
```

I have use this structure to get the memory information. 
But this structure is giving me everything separately.
How to convert this stuff into one final value that is the memory a process is using in Mb's. Just like shown in task Manager.

Comment: That would be the working set size

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/329913/what-is-memory-usage-and-virtual-memory-size-in-taskmgr

Comment: @UKMonkey but that's not matching value given in the task Manager,

Comment: in win10 task manager show exactly  `PrivateWorkingSetSize` member of `VM_COUNTERS_EX2` (look in *ntddk.h*). for get it need call `NtQueryInformationProcess` using `ProcessVmCounters`. the `GetProcessMemoryInfo` is only thin shell over `NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessVmCounters,..` and `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX` is repacked from `VM_COUNTERS_EX2` but `PrivateWorkingSetSize` no present in win32 version

Comment: What exactly do you think you mean by "memory a process is using"? It's a far more complicated matter than perhaps you imagine.